# What's the meaning of "breaking the tie among several equally liked names"?

Tags: meaning

> it’s worth considering those associations when breaking the tie among
>   several equally liked names

I know the meanings of the words. But I don't understand **who** "breaking the tie ..."

Do those associations break the tie? (assotiations & breaking?)

And as a result I don't undrestand the meaning of the last sentence.

The fuller text is:

> Names Influence Life Outcomes Every name is associated with
>   demographic baggage: information about the bearer’s age, gender,
>   ethnicity, and other basic personal features.[...] One reason why
>   personal names are so important, then, is that they allow people to
>   categorize us almost automatically [...]
>
> Names, then, have the capacity to shape our outcomes because they’re
>   tied to important concepts that have real meaning. Sometimes they’re
>   associated with racial groups or socioeconomic status, sometimes with
>   charity appeals or being called on last at school. Some of those
>   associations are positive and others are negative, and when you’re a
>   parent faced with a smorgasbord of choices, perhaps **it’s worth
>   considering those associations when breaking the tie among several
>   equally liked names.**

*Drunk Tunk Pink*  By Adam Alter

Answer (score 3):

The **who** is **you**:

> ... when **you’re** a parent faced with a smorgasbord of choices, perhaps it’s worth considering those associations when **[you're]** breaking the tie among several equally liked names.

He's talking about association between names. For a very basic, minimal example, consider the two names Joe and Bernard. The associations are that Joe is an ordinary name, while Bernard sounds a little more impressive. Of course, there's no rule. You have to be familiar with the name and culture to know which names are plain and which aren't.

Now, as a parent, you might be considering these two names and weigh them equally. In other words, there is a tie between Joe and Bernard. Then, yes, the associations break the tie. The author is suggesting that you use the associations in order to choose a name--in order to "break the tie."

Of course, there are more complicated associations, as suggested by the author.

Answer (score 1):

Please refer to [**tiebreaker**](https://www.wordnik.com/words/tiebreaker).

It is a means of deciding the best, when all seem to be equal.

So in this context, although the sentence is clumsy, your bolded text containing the phrase **breaking the tie** is recommending a way to make the decision of what name should be given — that is, considering what each name alludes to.

Answer (score 1):

[Tie](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tie) means :

> A result in a game or other competitive situation in which two or more
>   competitors or teams have the same score or ranking; a draw.

When you want to name your child, you will have copious options. The writer 
liken this choosing process to a competition and use the word tie in this context figuratively as if all the potential names are all equal at the first stage and there is a tie among them. The name you will choose will break the tie and will be winner.

The writer suggests that you take into consideration all the associations a name have when you choose it.

Comment: A minor point: I don’t think the writer is saying that “all potential names are equal at the first stage.” I think the implication is that the parents probably will narrow down the copious options to a few well-liked choices. Once that is accomplished, they would use the guidance provided to break the tie between those two or three names.